# Position tikzpictures side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, multicolumn

I have the following tikzpictures, and I would like to present them in two columns.
However, no matter what I try, whether it be `multicol` or `minipage` or `subcaption`, they stubbornly stay in one column. You may think this is a duplicate question, but I've tried all the others and they don't work!

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure} [b]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [pool/.style={circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
            inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm}]
        \node[pool] (A)              {A};
        \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Two-site exchange.}
        \label{fig:simple2}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure} %[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [pool/.style={circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
            inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm}]
        \node[pool] (A) {A};
        \node[pool] (B) [below left=of A] {B};
        \node[pool] (C) [below right=of A]{C};
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (C);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Partial three-site exchange.}
        \label{fig:partial3}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure} %[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [pool/.style={circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
            inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm}]
        \node[pool] (A) {A};
        \node[pool] (B) [below left=of A] {B};
        \node[pool] (C) [below=of A]{C};
        \node[pool] (D) [below right=of A]{D};
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (C);
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (D);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Partial four-site exchange.}
        \label{fig:partial4}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure} %[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [pool/.style={circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
            inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm}]
        \node[pool] (A) {A};
        \node[pool] (B) [below left=of A] {B};
        \node[pool] (C) [below right=of A]{C};
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
        \draw [<->] (A) -- (C);
        \draw [<->] (B) -- (C);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{General three-site exchange.}
        \label{fig:general3}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is nothing special about positioning a tikzpicture, it is positioned like an `X` If you put two X side by side they come side by side, if you put two X with a blank line between, they come one above the other, if you put two X in separate figure environments they float separately and will go one above the other

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing. I had nice newlines between each `minipage` environment. Of course, these behaved exactly as you describe.

Comment: oh no and I've deleted my answer so you'll have to accept egreg's and he'll pick up the points, oh well:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use just one `figure` environment. The figures can be put in minipages so as to ensure proper alignment, both vertical and horizontal.

I computed 5cm, find the best height. Since one caption turns out to be only one line long, a final adjustment has to be made (`\vspace{\baselineskip}`).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\caption{Two-site exchange.}\label{fig:simple2}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
            inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A) {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [below left=of A] {B};
  \node[pool] (C) [below right=of A]{C};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\caption{Partial three-site exchange.}\label{fig:partial3}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A) {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [below left=of A] {B};
  \node[pool] (C) [below=of A]{C};
  \node[pool] (D) [below right=of A]{D};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (C);
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\caption{Partial four-site exchange.}\label{fig:partial4}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A) {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [below left=of A] {B};
  \node[pool] (C) [below right=of A]{C};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (C);
  \draw [<->] (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\caption{General three-site exchange.}\label{fig:general3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hmm beat me by a minute, I'll delete

Comment: You sir, are a magician. I could have sworn I used just one figure with `minipages` inside it, but apparently I didn't. Thank you very much.

Comment: For future reference, @DavidCarlisle's comment on my answer was the missing link. `minipages` will only go side by side if there is NO NEWLINE between them.