# Insert multiple TikZ images side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions

I am using the following code borrowed from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210571/position-tikzpictures-side-by-side) with some modifications:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  pool/.style={
    circle, draw=blue!50, fill=blue!20, thick,
    inner sep=0pt, minimum size=10mm
  }
]
  \node[pool] (A)              {A};
  \node[pool] (B) [right=of A] {B};
  \draw [<->] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Numerous images.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `\caption` is not inserted properly as seen in the image below:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to your `minipage`s, i.e. `5cm`, specifies the height of those boxes, but the height doesn't stretch, so when your diagrams have a height bigger than 5cm, they extend outside the box, and you get a couple of "overfull vbox"-warnings in the log.

If you leave that argument empty, the box will have the height of the content in the box:

```
\begin{minipage}[b][][s]{.45\linewidth}
```

By the way, what is `s` intended to do here? I didn't think that was one of the valid options, but perhaps I'm mistaken.